# How do I unenroll my managed Acer ChromeBook?

Tags: chromebook

I have already tried <kbd>Esc</kbd> + power + efresh and it doesn't work. My ChromeBook is a school Acer Chromebook and extensions are blocked as well, and it has no guardian.

Is there any other way to unenroll it, and if not can I do it by opening the ChromeBook and going inside?

Comment: Unenroll it from where?

Comment: If the Chromebook belongs to the school, why are you trying to unenroll it? Are you supposed to be doing this? Have you spoken with your school technology staff?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that it was given to you by your school? If it was there is a chance it is marked for enterprise management.

> A message stating that "This device has been marked for enterprise
>   management by domain.com" means that the device is configured for
>   Forced [re-enrollment](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6352858) by the administrator of that domain.

Otherwise could you be more specific and add the exact model of the Chromebook?